# How can I size air springs?

Tags: springs

I am building a wagon for carrying heavy loads of up to 2000 lbs over uneven ground. It has 6 wheels each rated at 615 lbs capacity and a 4x8 foot bed. I am planning to use [air springs](https://www.mcmaster.com/products/air-springs/) to give each wheel a little of flex so it can move up and down independently of the other wheels. The problem is that I don't know how to size the air springs. McMaster shows the specs of their springs in terms of "Full Stroke Lifting Force @ Pressure " and "Beginning Stroke Lifting Force @ Pressure". How do I relate this to tires that are 615 pound capacity each?

Comment: Well, one nice thing is that these can be tuned easily by changing the pressure, so as long as you're slightly oversized you should be fine.

Comment: @Drew Define "oversized" quantitatively.

Comment: You will probably want the spring compressed some percentage under a static load. You can always increase this percentage by reducing the spring pressure, but you can only go up to the pressure rating. Therefore, at the maximum pressure, the spring compression must be less than your target.